How to use the local name of a state in Azure Trusted Signing identity validation?
in the identity validation process I can only choose the english names for states in the form (e.g. Bavaria instead of Bayern or Lower Saxony instead of Niedersachsen). Since I'm from germany, my former certificate was issued with the local state name instead of the english name. Is there any chance to allow the selection of local names in the identity validation?
Example:
Azure Trusted Signing Certificate Id:

CN=My Company, O=My Company, L=MyCity, S=Lower Saxony, C=DE

Old Certificate Id:

CN=My Company, O=My Company, L=MyCity, S=Niedersachsen, C=DE

I completed identity validation successfully, however the changed certificate id causes a different msix filename, which breaks the update mechanism. MSIX persistent identity is not really an option for me, since i have to support older windows builds as well.

The country/states can only be chosen from the prepopulated list. no option to enter values or change them.
